# Can't free malloc in c

Tags: c, malloc, free

I am new to C. I have below codes. After `free`, the first freed pointer give 0 length but not null, the second and third still have length > 0. Not sure if it is normal? Thanks.
Here is the output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqpF7.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char *str[3];
    char *aa = "helloworld0";
    char *bb = "helloworld1";
    char *cc = "helloworld2";
    str[0] = (char *)malloc(strlen(aa) + 1);
    strcpy(str[0], aa);
    str[1] = (char *)malloc(strlen(bb) + 1);
    strcpy(str[1], bb);
    str[2] = (char *)malloc(strlen(cc) + 1);
    strcpy(str[2], cc);

    char **strr = str;

    printf("Before free----Length:%ld,Content:%s,Address:%p\n",
           strlen(strr[1]), strr[1], strr[1]);
    free(strr[1]);
    if (strr[1]) printf("not NULL 1\n");
    printf("After free----Length:%ld,Content:%s,Address:%p\n\n",
           strlen(strr[1]), strr[1], strr[1]);

    printf("Before free----Length:%ld,Content:%s,Address:%p\n",
           strlen(strr[0]), strr[0], strr[0]);
    free(strr[0]);
    if (strr[0] == NULL) printf("not NULL 0\n");
    printf("After free----Length:%ld,Content:%s,Address:%p\n\n",
           strlen(strr[0]), strr[0], strr[0]);

    printf("Before free----Length:%ld,Content:%s,Address:%p\n",
           strlen(strr[2]), strr[2], strr[2]);
    free(strr[2]);
    if (strr[2]) printf("not NULL 2\n");
    printf("After free----Length:%ld,Content:%s,Address:%p\n\n",
           strlen(strr[2]), strr[2], strr[2]);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! After calling `free`, you can no longer access the data, so this program's behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

After passing a pointer value to `free`, any further use of that value has undefined behavior. Even `if (strr[1])` is invalid and does not have a meaningful result, even if in practice it normally reflects that the last time the value was meaningful, it was non-null.

The subsequent operation is even worse:

> ```
> printf("After free----Length:%ld,Content:%s,Address:%p\n\n",strlen(strr[1]),strr[1],strr[1]);
> ```

Here you're not only using the value `strr[1]` (a pointer), but passing a function that will use it to access an object at that address (`strlen`). This also has undefined behavior, and mechanically it ends up **accessing memory that no longer belongs to your program**. What this results in is a matter of how the compiler implementation handles undefined behavior it can see (note: it could even trap before letting you get this far, but it doesn't have to) and possibly on what the C library implementation (`free`) does with memory you've relinquished to it. It's possible that the address will no longer work and that accesses to it will fault and cause your program to crash. It's also possible that it ends up accessing memory that now belongs to the implementation, possibly with new contents stored there to track it for reuse. It's also possible that entirely different and unexpected results are produced.

In C you simply can't do this. After you `free` memory obtained by `malloc`, you're done with it. You can't process the pointer or the memory it pointed to before in any way. There is no way to "check if it was freed". Once it's freed, that's it.

Many programmers like to assign a null pointer value to any pointer object as soon as they free the memory it points to, to prevent inadvertently trying to access it later:

```
strr[1] = NULL;    // or = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Free memory actually means freeing ownership of specified place in the memory. The idea is that in the process of freeing it the variable it self can't write anymore off the given location but only read. In order to actually make the code safe after every free you should set the variable to NULL. It will redirect the variable off the last memory's sell it was pointing to and make the data unreadable from the variable it self. Instead the pointer will hold a NULL which is pre known state of a pointer free of ownership and thus may be used.

Comment: *can't write anymore off the given location but only read*? Once the block has been freed, both reading and writing using the pointer has undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

`free` means you are telling system:

> I do not need this memory anymore, you can use this memory anytime if you want.

But system does not guarantee when will it clean and re-use these memory.

Next time when you access this memory, maybe system has not cleaned it yet, or maybe it does. You just can not make sure whether it does. It is a **undefined behavior**.

You should add `strr[1]=NULL;` to prevent you accidentally access the space which you have already returned to system.